# Expression percentage difference for minimum and maximum values in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, expression

I am trying to write an expression for getting % difference in SSRS.
My current expression is:

```
(max(fields!MaximmumPrice.value) - min(fields!MinimumPrice.value))/  min(fields!MinimumPrice.value) * 100)
```

this is giving me the value in 5.88877292998.

My question is how can I have "%" sign in front of the no. and how can i get my answer to be "%5.88".

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo but that expression is missing a bracket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the textbox try something like:

```
="%" & Format(((max(fields!MaximmumPrice.value) - min(fields!MinimumPrice.value))
  / min(fields!MinimumPrice.value)) * 100, "N2")
```

If you would rather control this by the **Format** property at the textbox level, change the expression to:

```
=((max(fields!MaximmumPrice.value) - min(fields!MinimumPrice.value))
  / min(fields!MinimumPrice.value))
```

And set the **Format** property to:

```
%0,0.00;-%0,0.00;%0
```

Note that in this second case the `* 100` has been removed - if the **Format** expression contains `%` this will be done implicitly.

Comment: Great I am really a fresher on SSRS but it was really good knowing this.